# How can I inserting Thymeleaf fragment only if it exists, else ignore it

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm trying to inject a fragment into my page but I'm using a generic template and the fragment doesn't always exist. This is where I am right now but no matter what I try I always end up with a org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException

Any good ideas how to solve this?

I have tried this:

```
<script th:insert="${js_assets !=null} ? ~{'fragments/' + ${js_assets} :: ${js_assets} : ~{}" th:inline="javascript">...</script>
```

and this:

```
<script th:insert="${js_assets !=null} ? ~{'fragments/' + ${js_assets} :: ${js_assets} : _" th:inline="javascript">...</script>
```

And a lot of other things but always ends up with the same exception

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, it was not the insertion that was the problem... It was the fragment... This works:

```
<th:block th:if="${js_assets}"> 
    <script th:replace="@{'fragments/' + ${js_assets}} :: ${js_assets}">...</script> 
</th:block>
```